# Display the bullet of \item

Tags: beamer, enumerate

In the following code, at the place of `*step 2*`, I would like to display exactly [image]. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
\begin{block}{title}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item ... %Step 1
  \item ... %Step 2
  \item ... Go back to *Step 2*
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
```

Comment: Do you create your enumerated items in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)? And you just want to duplicate the numbered item in the "reference"?

Comment: It is in `beamer`, and the `\enumerate` is actually inside a `block` environment, that is why it is in blue...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is to use the `\label`, `\ref` mechanism, but defining a command to enclose the string produced by `\ref` inside a shaded ball like those used by `beamer`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\ballref[1]{%
\tikz \node[circle, shade,ball color=structure.fg,inner sep=0pt,%
  text width=8pt,font=\tiny,align=center] {\color{white}\ref{#1}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item ... %Step 1
  \item\label{ite:second} ... %Step 2
  \item ... Go back to Step~\ballref{ite:second}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the `french` option for `babel` makes `;` an active charcater, extra precuations will have to be taken:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\ballref[1]{%
\shorthandoff{;}\tikz \node[circle, shade,ball color=structure.fg,inner sep=0pt,%
  text width=8pt,font=\tiny,align=center] {\color{white}\ref{#1}};
\shorthandon{;}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{title}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item ... %Step 1
  \item\label{ite:second} ... %Step 2
  \item ... Go back to Step~\ballref{ite:second}
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}` between `\usetheme{Warsaw}` and `usepackage{tikz}`, that results in an error `ERROR: Paragraph ended before \tikz@next was complete.` Do you have any idea?

Comment: @SoftTimur yes; the problem is that `french` for `babel` makes `;` active. I've provided a solution in my updated answer.

Comment: Great... One last thing is that the `ballref` is always in gray, instead of blue here, do you know why?

Comment: @SoftTimur no, with so little information you provided. I need to see the settings of your document. Please add to your question a small *complete* document illustrating the problem mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I got it... because I use `\usetheme{Boadilla}`...

Comment: @SoftTimur in that case, use `structure.fg` for the color. I updated my answer with this modification.